# PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' and php_mysql.dll

Tags: php

When I check the PHP version using `php -v i` got error message like below

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>
> '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>
> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>
> '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysql.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

PHP 7.0.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.4 (cli)( NTS )

Please help me to fix the above issue.

Comment: This is very strange as it says is trying to load a DLL but you are on Linux. You need to detail all the steps you did before reaching this error. It seems to me you are trying to copy/paste some example and it does not apply to Ubuntu.

Comment: Currently i used this as web server. Could i reinstall the php?

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 14.04, the following should fix it.

cp /usr/lib/php/20151012/pdo_mysql.so /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_pdo_mysql.dll